# Unable to add a Camel Route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

A little background:

I am using Spring and Camel together with Java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    AbstractApplicationContext _context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "application-context.xml");
    _context.registerShutdownHook();

    MessageRoute _messageRoute = (MessageRoute) _context.getBean("messageRoute");
    SpringCamelContext _camelContext = _context.getBean(SpringCamelContext.class);
    _messageRoute.setContext(_camelContext);
    _camelContext.addRoutes(_messageRoute);

    Object lock = new Object();
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.wait();
    }

    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) _context).close();

}
```

[main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
[main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
[main] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
[main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'messageRoute'
[main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext#0'
[main] DEBUG o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Adding routes from builder: Routes: []
[main] DEBUG o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Adding routes from builder: Routes: []

> I have tried using DefaultCamelContext as well but the problem is it's just not adding the route class. The MessageRoute class is a simple class extending the RouteBuilder. My observation tells me the line containing: _context.getBean("messageRoute") might have an issue because it's not really passing any route to the RouteBuilder reference.

[image: debugger view]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I fixed it! Camel wasn't adding an instance of the Route class sitting inside the spring container because in the configure method, one needs an actual path saying from().to().

Pretty funny though that it wasn't throwing any error and even refused the add the ApplicationContext bean to routes.

Answer (score 0):

To add Java routes in XML, just use `<routeBuilder ref="myBeanName"/>` inside `<camelContext>`

See the Camel documentation: http://camel.apache.org/spring.html at the section *Using Java Code*

Comment: I know I can try the XML way but this is how I used to add routes in Camel 2.10 and they would work fine. I can probably go ahead and do it the XML way but why is Camel not honoring the beans created in ApplicationContext of Spring. I need a good reasoning here. May be I am doing something wrong that I can't see or may be its a genuine spring+camel issue.

Comment: The same code works with camel 2.10 and spring 3.x! Also, not sure how my question was so wrong that it was downvoted.